# How can I get the retry count within a delegate executed through Polly retry policy?

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic

I'm implementing Polly to retry requests in my C# web app.  My sample code is included in this post.  The code works as expected but the last parameter passed to `CreateFile()` (currently hard-coded as 0) needs to be the value of `retryAttempt`. How can I get the value of `retryAttempt` within the `Execute`'s Action?

```
return Policy
    .Handle<HttpException>(x => x.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
    .Or<StorageException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(maxRetryCount, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Math.Pow(retryIntervalMs, retryAttempt)))
    .Execute(() => CreateFile(fileContent, containerName, fileName, connectionString, 0));
```

Comment: Note also that Polly has some [specific retry overloads helpful for 429 responses](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#retryafter-when-the-response-specifies-how-long-to-wait). if the 429 response specifies how long to wait. The retry policy can be made to wait for exactly the retry-after duration specified in the 429 response.

Answer (score 20):

Polly does not provide an `.Execute(...)` overload where retry count is one of the input parameters to the delegate passed to `.Execute(...)`.  This is because retry is only one of many Polly policies, whereas the shape of `.Execute(...)` overloads must be general to all policy types.

For the use case described in the question, simply:

```
int count = 0;
return Policy
    .Handle<HttpException>(x => x.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
    .Or<StorageException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(maxRetryCount, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Math.Pow(retryIntervalMs, retryAttempt)))
    .Execute(() => CreateFile(fileContent, containerName, fileName, connectionString, count++));
```

---

An alternative approach uses Polly's execution-scoped `Polly.Context`: an instance of this travels with each execution, and is available to all parts of an execution.

Retry policy already passes the retry count to the `onRetry` delegate, so the policy can capture this into the execution-scoped `Context`:

```
var retryPolicyCapturingCountIntoContext =
    Policy
        .Handle<HttpException>(x => x.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
        .Or<StorageException>()
        .WaitAndRetry(
            maxRetryCount,
            retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Math.Pow(retryIntervalMs, retryAttempt)),
            onRetry: (response, delay, retryCount, context) =>
            {
                context["retrycount"] = retryCount;
            });
```

In the delegate executed through the policy, we can pick the retry count out of `Context` (taking care to handle the case when no retries have yet happened):

```
retryPolicyCapturingCountIntoContext
    .Execute(context =>
    {
        int retryCount = (context.TryGetValue("retrycount", out var retryObject) && retryObject is int count) ? count : 0;
        CreateFile(fileContent, containerName, fileName, connectionString, retryCount);
    }, new Context());
```

If you prefer to avoid the noise of the `context.TryGetValue(...)` defensive code, you can alternatively choose to ensure you always initialise `context["retrycount"]` before you start an execution:

```
var myContext = new Polly.Context { {"retrycount ", 0} };
retryPolicyCapturingCountIntoContext
    .Execute(
         context => CreateFile(fileContent, containerName, fileName, connectionString, (int)context["retrycount"]),
         myContext);
```

---

---

For users who want to capture the retry count of each retry as it happens, say for logging, see the [Polly retry examples](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/README.md#retry) showing how `retryCount` is passed as an input parameter to the `onRetry` delegate which can be configured on the policy.  Further examples [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/README.md#policy-keys-and-context-data).

For users who want to capture the overall number of retries used for an operation to succeed, in a generalised way - say for telemetry as part of some general execution-dispatch infrastructure code - see [these examples in Steve Gordon's blog](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/polly-using-context-to-obtain-retry-count-diagnostics), which use the `Context`-based approach.